# Change voice pitch on audio recording

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

I am currently using `AVAudioRecorder` to record a spoken word(sometimes just one word, sometimes a whole sentence) and I need to store that audio with higher pitch on the voice.

I am quite new to the `AudioKit`. Any recommendations how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two approaches.  One, you could use AKPitchShifter which is a real time pitch shifter.  Set the shift, and then use AKRecorder to recorder the stream.  Next, you could record the audio first and then use AKTimePitch to pitch (or time) stretch the result, render the updated file offline.

Comment: I did use the `AKTimePitch` and it works great, thanks.